# Inter process communication between sandboxed Mac app and plugin

Tags: macos, ipc, shared-memory, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I have an application `App A` which shares `data` with a macOS plugin using IPC (shared memory). The plugin is loaded in another 3rd party `App B`:

```
App A <--- data ---> Plugin / App B
```

Now I am looking for a way to get this working with `App A` being sandboxed. The `App Groups Entitlement` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups) seems to be the correct tool for allowing IPC between two applications. But the problem with my architecture is that  the communication is between `App A` (whose identifier is known) and a plugin (identifier is known) and a third party `App B` (identifier is not known).

Is there a way to communicate between the sandboxed `App A` and the plugin running in `App B` without knowing `App B`'s identifier?

Regards,